# Using JavaScript in mobile web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile

I need to use JavaScript in a form for mobile web application.

I need some information about it, related to browser compatibility as well as way to use JavaScript in mobile web applications (syntax).

Answer (score 6):

It's a nightmare. It's like working with web-browsers in the 90's but with the manager expectations of tomorrow.

I strongly recommend you determine your target platforms in terms of regions, software, and actual hardware since the market is much more fragmented than the web and a large number of mobile devices have issues with CSS, JS and even XHTML ranging from painful to not-on-this-platform.

The good news is that android and iphone are pushing the field rapidly. The bad news is that makes a lot of the sources you'll google badly out-of-date.

Some references:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/mobileOK-basic10-tests/#test_objects_or_script
- http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/getting-started-with-mobile-ajax
- http://mobiforge.com/

Especially that last one :)

Comment: a thousand time this! I work in mobile development, my first question for any mobile project is which devices are we supporting! It informs all other decisions.

Answer (score 5):

The reality have changed since this question was asked. Modern smartphones support browsers, that are compatibile with their desktop big brothers, with same JavaScript support. However, still there are differences how application is displayed and how it is operated, you can't rely on drag-and-drop, there are some rendering differences, f.g. in GWT-Ext Showcase on Opera Mobile tab close buttons are not rendered. So you should not rely on modern JavaScript 'magic framework' such as Ext.

Comment: I agree GWT works seamlessly well on the major browser platforms on mobile phones, tablets, and browsers alike.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the "it's a nightmare" comment.

Some tips:

- For simple scripts, go right back to JavaScript basics - no JS frameworks - think document.getElementById();
- Always make sure your JavaScript is valid. If you have an object, make sure you have commas and semi-colons in the right place. An easy way to check this is in Internet Explorer - check in the bottom left for the valid or invalid JavaScript icon.
- Make sure your Javascript is XML valid - Blackberry's won't like it if it's not.
- For something more complex, check out jquery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/ - some nice stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with annakata,

It is a minefield trying to work with JavaScript on a mobile phone in fact we(I work for a  mobile agency) tend to recommend to clients that you don't use JavaScript in your mobile pages.

If you have to use JavaScript then look into

- WURLF - http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/
- MobiForge - http://mobiforge.com/
- MobileElements -    http://www.mobileelements.com/

And I would recommend creating an iPhone only site that has all the cool functionality and then a plain site for everyone else so that it works well for them.

Also remember you can use device anywhere for testing on multiple phones as well

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use new framework for mobile web applications Sencha http://www.sencha.com/

This framework supports wide range of mobile platforms like Adroid, iPhone and others...

Good luck,
Yevgeniy V.
Softjourn Inc.
Software developer.

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution to target multiple devices (IPhone, Android, BlackBerry, Bada ...) and take advantage of innovative components is to use the JavaScript Toolkit [Wink](http://www.winktoolkit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Khushi,

I have just founded a framework called PhoneGap, you build your whole app using javascript, html5 and css. You even can play with device native features.

Take a look at for more information http://www.phonegap.com/about .

Comment: You'll still need to build the web app. PhoneGap just provides you with the loader for the device and access to it's components.  I used jquery.mobile before and was very much modelled after iPhone "App"-like behaviour and a good starter framework if you don't want to worry about a lot of the cavaets of mobile dev.

Answer (score 0):

You may know Patrick H. Lauke, who wrotes the [quirksmode blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/). He started to work with mobile phones in the not so recent past.

He is publishing his work on the same website in the same wonderful quality of his.

Browsers in the new mobile phones are getting better, that's true, but unfortunately even crazier bugs are popping up.

Not all are javascript related, but you could check his mobile pages at:

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/