# coverting existing flash with cakephp website into mobile version

Tags: cakephp, mobile

How to convert the existing flash site into mobile version existing site in  form of the cakephp frame work. We thought that html ,css,php,javascript may work all mobiles.We dont know exactly. Please tell us how many possible way to develop existing site into mobile version and also need to detect the from which browser the request is coming whether mobile browser or pc browser.

The existing site link is :[This site convert into mobile version](http://www.level7group.com)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://madething.org/post/661607317/mobile-browser-detection-and-optimization-in-cakephp) post. PHP is handled on the server. No browser needs to support it. [CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html) and XHTML are supported pretty well by mobile browsers. [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316876/using-javascript-in-mobile-web-application-wap) support is limited.